# What's the best practice to connect a table to a junction table in relational database design?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I'm building a relational database that will act as a CRM for a travel company. I have removed tables and attributes to make this as simple as possible. Users will send quotes to customers.

A hotel can have many rooms (e.g. hotel 1 can have both a twin room and a triple room).

A room can have many hotels (e.g. a both hotels 1 and 2 can have a twin room).

Let's say a customer has a group of 6.
A user could send this customer a quote for hotel 1 with either 3x twin rooms or 2x triple rooms.

A quote will need to contain the hotel and appropriate room type and room type quantities.

Whats the best practice to connect table HOTEL_ROOM_JUNCTION to QUOTE as they key is a multi-attribute, composite key?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Noting the `Relational Database` tag.</sub>

### Problem

1. There is a lack of precision in your declarations:

   > A hotel can have many rooms (e.g. hotel 1 can have both a twin room and a triple room).
   >   A room can have many hotels (e.g. a both hotels 1 and 2 can have a twin room).

   I think you mean **RoomType**.  From the rest of your declarations, the system you are implementing is for Quotations of rooms across all hotels, not a room booking system for each of the hotels.  That is, you need to track RoomType, not Room, per Hotel.
2. The tables as given are not Relational tables, they do not have any of the requirements that make them Relational.  When you start with stamping an `id` field on every file, it cripples the data analysis & data modelling exercise that is required to create a set of Relational tables.  That is anti-Relational:

   - physical pointers such as `record id` are expressly prohibited in the *Relational Model*.
   - The Primary Key must be "made up from the data".
   - *I appreciate that you have been schooled in that, due to the marketing and promotion of primitive methods as "relational".*

   .
   For starters, each logical row (not physical record with a `record id`) must be unique.

   [image: AlexProblem]
3. The fields in each file should not be prefixed with the filename.  In SQL (the data sub-language for the implementation of the *Relational Model*), the fully qualified address for a column is:

   `[server.][database.][owner.][table.]column`

   with defaults (obvious) for each element. If a column is ambiguous, simply prefix it with the table name.

   - Primary Keys are a special case.  In order to avoid confusion (and now, to allow the new `NATURAL JOIN`), they should be the full name, in both the PK and FK locations.  An `id` on every file would ensure buggy code.

### Relational Data Model

If I address all those issues, and model the data according to the *Relational Model*, it would be:

[image: AlexTA]

#### Notation

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993.
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for those who are new to the *Relational Model*, or its modelling method.  Note that IDEF1X models are rich in detail and precision, showing all required details, whereas home-grown models have far less than that.  Which means, the notation has to be understood.

#### Content

1. **Relational Key**
   In order to make the logical rows unique, we need to make a Key from the data.  The users know their data, they know what is unique and what is not.  Usually they will have a ShortName for such things as Company; Hotel; Customer; etc.

   - *If you do not communicate with the user, there is no chance of supplying the user's needs.*
   - `Hotel, UserName, Customer` are ShortNames, which are unique, which therefore are the Primary Key.  (More, later)
   - Relational Keys are composites, because they preserve the natural data hierarchies.  Get used to it.
     *If you need the DDL for composite Keys, please ask.*
   - Presuming that a `Hotel` may be a chain or franchise, we need a `Location` to make a specific hotel that has rooms unique.
2. The following are discrete Facts, and should not be mixed together (doing so will lead to complex constraints and horrendous SQL code):

   - **HotelRoomType**
     that a `Hotel.Location` has a particular `RoomType`; and the `Price`
   - **RoomTypeAvailable**
     that a `Hotel.Location` has one of those `RoomTypes` available on a particular `Date`; and the `Number`.
     *I presume there is a file from the hotels that you will be importing on a daily basis: this is the central table for that, with the constraints, of course.*
   - **Quote**
     that an `User` is providing a `Quote` that is requested by a single `Customer`, for a single `TravelDate`, for a single `Hotel.Location`.  This allows separate `Quotes` for separate `Hotel.Locations` for a single `TravelDate`; `Quotes` for a `Customer` for more than one `TravelDate`; etc.
     .
     *If you need multiple* `Hotel.Locations` *(and their* `RoomTypes`*) on a single* `Quote`, *let me know in the comments, and I will update the data model.*
   - **QuoteRoomType**
     that a `Quote` contains a line item which is a single `RoomType` in the single `Hotel.Location` that is available on the `TravelDate`.
3. **Relational Integrity**
   A logical feature of the *Relational Model*, which is distinct from Referential Integrity, which is a physical feature in SQL.  It is not possible to achieve this in a Record Filing System with `record ids` as "primary keys", not even an advanced and progressed one (after the various errors in the initial RFS have been corrected).  Genuine logical Keys ("made up from the data") are required.

   - In `RoomTypeAvailable`, we have constrained:

     - `RoomTypes` to that which the `Hotel.Location` actually has (in `HotelRoomType`)
     - **AND** is actually available on `Date`.
   - In `QuoteRoomType`, we have constrained:

     - `Hotel.Location` to that which is in the `Quote`,
     - **AND** `RoomTypes` to that which is available in `Hotel.Location` (in `HotelRoomType`),
     - **AND** which is available on the `TravelDate` (`RoomTypeAvailable.Date` "maps to" `QuoteRoomType.TravelDate`).

---

### 1960's Record Filing System • Anti-Relational, Sold as "relational"

> This section is relevant for those who prescribe a `Record ID` field as "primary key" in every file.  And somehow think that that is "relational".  Others can safely skip it.

For comparison, here is the set of files that one would come up with, if one followed the techniques and methods that are promoted and marketed by Date; Darwen; Fagin; et al crowd, falsely proposed as "relational".

[image: AlexRFS]

- This a **"mature" or "advanced" model**, the fourth or fifth iteration.  It has a number of improvements over the initial RFS.  The initial or second or third iteration would not be equivalent enough to offer a comparison:

  - the Facts that are required to support the system have been determined (as opposed to the initial model, the record perspective, which is oblivious to Facts).
  - the content of the records have been improved to prevent duplicates, to the extent possible given the record content (but it is still streets behind the uniqueness provided in a Relational data model)

#### Fails Relational

Nevertheless it has no Relational features, which are logical.  It has only the physical features of SQL reference-ability.  Just a few of the many failures, which the mob prescribes as "relational":

1. Duplicate rows (logical) are not prevented, because rows are not defined.
2. **No Relational Integrity**
   which depends on Relational Keys.  (Refer to the Relational Keys detailed above.)

   - Eg. `QuoteRoomType` is constrained to ***any*** `RoomTypeAvailable`.
     It is not possible to constrain it to:

     - the `HotelId` that is referenced in the `Quote` only,
     - **OR** to `RoomTypes` that exist in the `HotelId` only,
     - **OR** to `RoomTypesAvailable` that are available on the `TravelDate` only.
3. One additional field, and one additional index, for the `Record id` on every file.  That will have a marvellous effect on performance.
4. Horrendous navigation and query code.
5. **No Relational Power**
   When two distal files need to be `JOINed`, each of the intermediate files must be **additionally** `JOINed`, something that is not required in a Relational database.  That is because it breaks the **Access Path Independence Rule**, a concept that the razor gang have not been understand in the fifty years since the advent of the *RM*.  But they will come up with yet another abnormal "normal form", to add to their bag of seventeen thus far.

#### More, Not Fewer, Joins

Let’s look at what that means.  We need a query to provide statistics for RoomTypes that have been quoted for previous year, so that hotels can re-arrange their room types to suit the expected traffic.

- Using the Relational data model (separate section above), we would code:

```
SELECT RoomType.RoomType,  -- Relational database
       Description,
       SUM( NumRoom )
    FROM RoomType
        JOIN QuoteRoomType ON RoomType.RoomType = QuoteRoomType.RoomType
    WHERE DATEPART( YY, TravelDate ) = DATEPART( YY, GETDATE() ) - 1
    GROUP BY RoomType.RoomType, Description
```

- Using the Record Filing System data model, which is the result of following the advice of the Date; Darwen; Fagin; philipxy; AntC; et al gang, which is falsely marketed as "relational" (above), we would be forced to code:

```
SELECT RoomType,           -- Record Filing System
       Description,
       SUM( NumRoom )
    FROM RoomType
        JOIN HotelRoomType
            ON RoomType.RoomTypeId = HotelRoomType.RoomTypeId
        JOIN RoomTypeAvailable 
            ON HotelRoomType.HotelRoomTypeId = RoomTypeAvailable.HotelRoomTypeId
        JOIN QuoteRoomType
            ON RoomTypeAvailable.RoomTypeAvailableId = QuoteRoomType.RoomTypeAvailableId
        JOIN Quote
            ON QuoteRoomType.QuoteId Quote.QuoteId
    WHERE DATEPART( YY, TravelDate ) = DATEPART( YY, GETDATE() ) - 1
    GROUP BY RoomType, Description
```

- Gotta love the QueryPlan for that, that the SQL platform will produce.

  - Re-arranging the order of the `JOINs` might improve the tortoise.
  - Resorting to moving fragments such as “partial FDs” or “MVDs” around, might improve it.
- Perhaps deploying more “candies”, plus the required additional indices, all over the place, will help.  But wait, that would be **duplication on a mass scale**, it would break Normalisation, there would be **Update Anomalies** everywhere one looks.
- Note that that result set has **no reliability; no credibility**.  Why ?  Because, as already proved, the `QuoteRoomType` is not constrained to the `Quote.`Hotel (referenced by `HotelId`);
  or to the `Quote.TravelDate`; 
  or to the `RoomTypes` available in `Quote`Hotel (referenced by `HotelId`).

  - Further, there may well be duplicates, because prevention can only be partially implemented.  The result of which is unreliable result sets.

#### Simplicity vs Complexity

If you have the interest and the stamina, you can attempt to elevate the RFS by muddling through their "partial dependencies"; "transitive dependencies"; "candies"; "multi-valued dependencies"; etc, all of which are neither defined in, nor required in, the *Relational Model*.  They are expressly for use in the Record Filing Systems of the last century.

- First, the RFS paradigm (marketed as "relational") forces a record mindset, instead of a data-only mindset.
- Second, it breaks everything down into fragments, instead of understanding the atoms; the Facts, in their full context (data hierarchies).
- Third, it gives you a morass of complexity to handle the fragments, that have no relevance when handling atoms.

When you are done, all that complexity in the Record Filing System will still not be anywhere near the simplicity of the equivalent Relational data model: it will have:

- No Relational Integrity (yes, yes, we have Declarative Referential Integrity, and that only for physical records, not for logical rows)
- No Relational Power (multiple forced `JOINs` in every query)
- No Relational Speed (those additional columns and indices have an effect).

And the navigation and query code will be horrendous, and prone to errors.

---

Please feel feel to ask specific questions.  Also, please supply clarifications as noted, and I will update the data model.

---

Answer (score 0):

Since a specific room can only exist in one hotel the table HOTEL_ROOM_JUNCTION is redundant. So pk hotel_id is fk in rooom, and pk in room is a concat key of hotel_id and room_id.

If one quote can consist of several rooms you need a connecting table between quote and room them with fk quote_id, room_id and hotel_id and those three will be the pk in that table. (As a rule of thumb, that kind of table will usually need a timestamp).

(as a side note; I would name the tables QUOTES, ROOMS and HOTELS since they contain many)

EDIT: I miss read the question somewhat .. to make my model as OP wants I need to add ROOM_TYPES with pk room_type_id which will be fk (not null) in ROOMS but not part of the pk.

Comment: For the new junction table fk quote_id, room_id and hotel_id - would I need the hotel_id in this table as it's already in the ROOMS table and represented by the room_id? Thanks again :)

Comment: If your id's are just counters you don't need to use composite keys. Weather to use composite keys or not is a much larger question.